# Incorrect System Uptime

Tags: reboot, oracle-linux, uptime

Recently, in an Oracle Linux (either 6 or 7) based virtual machine, I faced any issue where system uptime was apparently wrong.

```
# who -b
  system boot  2019-07-24 13:21

# last reboot
reboot   system boot  3.8.13-44.1.4.el Wed Jul 24 13:21 - 23:24  (10:03)    

wtmp begins Wed Aug 22 11:09:06 2018

# hwclock --show    
Wed 24 Jul 2019 11:26:11 PM CEST  -0.956063 seconds

# uptime
 23:24:36 up 10:03,  3 users,  load average: 0.63, 0.51, 0.68

# cat /proc/uptime
36320.87 267407.58
```

The system was indeed rebooted at 13:21 which is correctly listed in "who -b" but somehow "last reboot" and "uptime" is only showing "10:03". Hardware clock value is correct and uptime value is updating with time with every minute as expected. I didn't got the chance to re-look at the issue in detail but may soon have to work on it.

Any suggestions why this might have happened and how to rectify it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last reboot` correctly shows the machine was rebooted at 13:21.

What is in brackets is just time epleased since the action.

Same as `uptime`, shows system was up for 10 hours and 3 minutes.

Comment: Seems I misjudged the uptime value in minutes. Anyways thanks for clarification.